# How to do a bootstrap on a dataset in Python

Tags: python

I am working on this coursework that requires a dataset to be sampled with replacement. I want to do a bootstrap on the age counts data

I have gotten the cumulative sum of my age population as this

```
stairs = np.cumsum(age_counts)
```

defined a function to create a single bootstrap

bootstrapping the data:

```
n = int(5e5)
```

create a single bootstrap:

```
def single_bootstrap():

    bootstrap = np.zeros([101, 2])
    bootstrap[:, 0] = range (0, 101)

    for i in range(n):
        i = np.random.randint (1, n+1)

        age = int(np.argwhere(stairs>i)[0]);

        bootstrap[age, 1] += 1

    return bootstrap
```

How do I get to repeat it n number of times(i.e 200 times). Because the code that I wrote does not seem to return any value.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You are missing the n variable value inside the function.

> I'm giving the same code below, and It's working :)

```
 from db import db
 import numpy as np

 bootstrap = np.zeros([101, 2])
 bootstrap[:, 0] = range(0,101)


 n = 200;

for i in range(n):
     i = np.random.randint (1, n+1)
     age = int(i);
     bootstrap[age, 1] += 1

print bootstrap
```